# what is the difference between distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy of CoreLocationManager?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-location, cllocationmanager

what is the difference between distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy of CoreLocationManager. To get the current location updates do I need to set these two values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**distanceFilter** is how far the user must move, in order for a new location update to be issued by the system.

**desiredAccuracy** is how long the device will keep trying more and more accurate methods to get the current location.  If you set this really high cell towers may be enough and it won't even wake up the GPS, saving battery.

Comment: Hi could u explain a lil more on ur answer for statemnt -" If you set this really high cell towers may be enough and it won't even wake up the GPS, saving battery."

Comment: The device can tell where it is within, say 10 kilometers just by knowing what cell towers are nearby.  So if you set the accuracy to 10km it could potentially be happy with just using that data and not enable the GPS.